# setTimeout for delaying opening a popup in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need for delaying opening of a popup.
This is the code of my popup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pmauid = 'Numbers';
var pmawid = 'Numbers';
var fq = '0';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mypopnetwork.com"></script>
```

So, I need for apply a delay in this part of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mypopnetwork.com"></script>
```

If I editing in this way, nothing happened:

```
<script type="text/javascript" window.setTimeout() src="http://mypopnetwork.com"></script>
```

Maybe I wrong syntax. This popup is normally open after clicking on an alertbox.

I tried also in this way:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mypopnetwork.com"></script>;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: You cannot just inject JavaScript into HTML and expect it to magically work. You could dynamically load the script instead and defer the loading as long as you want.

Comment: Mmm How I can do this?

Comment: Quick search leads me to this link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp - have you ever tried to find a solution first by yourself?

Comment: See [Include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/950087/218196).

Comment: Yes, I tried this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp   But not works. I need for apply a delay in my popup code. Example: 1 popup start in 4 seconds after I click on button of alertbox.

Comment: I can use JQuery for load the script in this way: $.getScript("my_lovely_script.js", function(){

   alert("Script loaded but not necessarily executed.");

});      And simply apply a delay?

Comment: why are you loading a script via jQuery? Plus that code does not look like a popup.

Comment: it was a simply question, I haven't try with JQuery. The complete code of my popup is this <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mypopnetwork.com/pma.js">

Answer (score 0):

For one, you are treating JavaScript as if it were some sort of attribute, It should be in between the `<script>` tags (if your doing it inline) like:

```
<script>
    // your code here
</script>
```

or if you want to reference a JavaScript file:

```
<script src="./whatever.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://foo.com/script.js"></script>
```

Second off, you need to provide a callback and a timeout length to `setTimeout()`. So in the end, you code should look like:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    alert("whatever");
}, 5000);
```

Where the callback is what you want to fire after the timer and 500 is the delay in milliseconds.

Comment: The problem is: I have 2 popups, I need for add a delay in them code. I tried also with setTimeout(function () {
    ; //my pop code
}, 5000);

Comment: and what is your issue?

Comment: Not works. With this code setTimeout(function () { ; //my pop code }, 5000);  I see only the text in my page, popcode disappared.

Comment: of course. You have a random semicolon and the callback contains nothing but a comment. To create a popup use `alert()`

Comment: I starting my popup with a AlertBox. When I click on  the button the pop start perfect. I unknow how apply a simply delay on code of popup. Because I use 2 popups, If I not apply a delay, them starting together and 1 is blocked by Chrome. So, I need of a delay on 1 pop code.